# How can I avoid a warning when calling merge(indicator=True) on two data-frames with multi-level column indexes?

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a data-frame with a multi-level column index. Simplified into a contrived example, let's say it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd


letters_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'A'],
    ['b', 'B'],
    ['c', 'C'],
    ['d', 'D'],
    ['e', 'E'],
    ['f', 'F']
], columns=['lower', 'upper'])

letters_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['letter'], letters_df.columns])

display(letters_df)
```

|  | letter |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | lower | upper |
| 0 | a | A |
| 1 | b | B |
| 2 | c | C |
| 3 | d | D |
| 4 | e | E |
| 5 | f | F |

Now suppose I have another data-frame that I want to merge it with, like this:

```
vowels_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [True],
    [False],
    [False],
    [False],
    [True],
    [False]
], columns=['is_vowel'])

display(vowels_df)
```

|  | is_vowel |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | True |
| 5 | False |

I can't merge the two data-frames directly, because if I try to do that, I'll get an error:

> UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left,1 on the right)

So, before I merge, I'll add a second dummy level to `vowels_df`:

```
vowels_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([vowels_df.columns, ['dummy']])

display(vowels_df)
```

|  | is_vowel |
| --- | --- |
|  | dummy |
| 0 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | True |
| 5 | False |

Now I can merge the two data-frames.

```
merged = letters_df.merge(vowels_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, indicator=True)

display(merged)
```

|  | letter |  | is_vowel | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | lower | upper | dummy |  |
| 0 | a | A | True | both |
| 1 | b | B | False | both |
| 2 | c | C | False | both |
| 3 | d | D | False | both |
| 4 | e | E | True | both |
| 5 | f | F | False | both |

All good... **except** that I get a warning message:

> PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.

You'll notice that there's no `drop` in my code above, so this appears to be something internal to the `merge` method.

Given that I'm not actually calling `drop` myself, how can I prevent this warning from being emitted? I tried calling `sort_index` on the two data-frames before calling `merge`, but that has no effect.

Removing the `indicator=True` parameter to `merge` gets rid of the warning, but in my real-world case I'm doing an 'outer' join, and I need to have that indicator column.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that "works" (but which avoids the question) is to flatten the multi-level column index before merging, and un-flatten it afterwards.

So, if I have the original two data-frames:

```
display(letters_df)
```

|  | letter |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | lower | upper |
| 0 | a | A |
| 1 | b | B |
| 2 | c | C |
| 3 | d | D |
| 4 | e | E |
| 5 | f | F |

```
display(vowels_df)
```

|  | is_vowel |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | True |
| 5 | False |

...then instead of adding a second level to `vowels_df`, I can flatten the column index on `letters_df`:

```
letters_df.columns = letters_df.columns.to_flat_index()

display(letters_df)
```

|  | (letter, lower) | (letter, upper) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | A |
| 1 | b | B |
| 2 | c | C |
| 3 | d | D |
| 4 | e | E |
| 5 | f | F |

Now I can merge without getting a warning:

```
merged = letters_df.merge(vowels_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, indicator=True)

display(merged)
```

|  | (letter, lower) | (letter, upper) | is_vowel | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | A | True | both |
| 1 | b | B | False | both |
| 2 | c | C | False | both |
| 3 | d | D | False | both |
| 4 | e | E | True | both |
| 5 | f | F | False | both |

...but then I need to work a bit harder to restore the multi-level column index:

```
tuples = [(c, '') if type(c) == str else c for c in merged.columns.values]

merged.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

display(merged)
```

|  | letter |  | is_vowel | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | lower | upper |  |  |
| 0 | a | A | True | both |
| 1 | b | B | False | both |
| 2 | c | C | False | both |
| 3 | d | D | False | both |
| 4 | e | E | True | both |
| 5 | f | F | False | both |

So that *works*, but (a) it's a tad fiddly(!), and (b) it doesn't really answer the question.